# AWS Cognito ListUsers InvalidParameterException using AttributesToGet on custom attributes

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Using the following AWS Lambda-based app client, I'm trying to list all users from my Cognito user pool.

```
let AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const COGNITO_CLIENT = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider()
COGNITO_CLIENT.listUsers({
  UserPoolId: 'MyUserPoolId',
  AttributesToGet: ['default_attribute', 'custom:my_attribute']
}, callback)
```

Everything works fine when querying for all attributes by default (`AttributesToGet: []  // or excluding this field altogether`). However, when targeting custom attributes, the InvalidParameterException is raised. This is using the Amazon SDK for Node.js.

Targeting default attributes are allowed though:

```
AttributesToGet: ['email', 'name', /* other non-custom */]
```

Comment: Ensure `AttributesToGet` match the pattern `[\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{S}\\p{N}\\p{P}]+`

Comment: Make sure the client has read access to the custom attribute. If the attribute is created after the client then by default the client does not have access to it. It is under details for the client and then click the link to change the access.

Comment: I have checked and the app client has read access. When I ask for all attributes to be returned, the custom attributes are returned. When I target them using `AttributesToGet`, I get that exception

Comment: The code looks correct. The call is exact (up to the name of the custom attribute) as in my project, so consider the problem to be an environment error. Re-check IDs and once again the permissions. Check that your letters are ASCII and there are no typographic symbols like nbsp. Create a new pool and try with the new pool. ...

Answer (score 5):

Please remove the "AttributesToGet" and try.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. However, I am on the Cognito team and we don't support search on custom attributes at this point.

Comment: Can that part about AttributesToGet be documented? The filter parameter documentation indeed states that it cannot search on custom attributes, but I'm certain that the AttributesToGet section doesn't specify a caveat that it implicitly uses the same search algorithm as in the filter, and therefore does not allow targeting custom attributes. I find it counterintuitive though. It's just targeting returned attributes, not exactly a search. It should be able to handle custom attributes as targets for AttributeToGet